# Spring Boot: Add new Extension-AcceptHeader mappings

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-accept-header

Within a normal Spring Application, I have:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, MediaType> getDefaultMediaTypes() {
        Map<String, MediaType> mediaTypes = super.getDefaultMediaTypes();
        mediaTypes.put("extension", new MediaType("foo", "bar"));
        return mediaTypes;
    }
}
```

So I can do something like:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "foo/bar")
public void test() { ... }
```

And then call:

```
http://.../myResource.extension
```

---

When I do this with Spring Boot, then `extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport` would prevent all the auto configuration.

So how can I easily register new Extension-Accept-Header mappings with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, I have verified the code with Boot 1.2.1.RELEASE

```
@Configuration
 public class EnableWebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, MediaType> getDefaultMediaTypes() {
        Map<String, MediaType> mediaTypes = super.getDefaultMediaTypes();
        mediaTypes.put("extension", new MediaType("foo", "bar"));
        return mediaTypes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring Boot config seems to be really endlessly! `:D`. I looked at `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`, but didn't figure out that it injects its own `EnableWebMvcConfiguration`. I will try it in a few minutes!

Answer (score 1):

according to avi's answer, we should use `extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration`

For adding additional extensions and media types, it might be more easy to just override `configureContentNegotiation`:

```
@Override
protected void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer
        .mediaType("extension", new MediaType("foo", "bar"));
}
```